# Email Notifications from Google Sheet based On date in row if date is today

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I a permit technician for a company and would like my spreadsheet to send me an email notification if the value in row E equals todays date. I have no clue what I am doing. I would like the email to come around 7am.

I am lost of apps scripts, I donot want a data set to showon my spreadsheet. I have clue how to do this

Answer (score 0):

A function running off of a time based trigger.

```
function sendEmail() {
  const row = 1;//edit
  const col = 5;//edit
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//edit
  const d = new Date(sh.getRange(row,col).getValue());
  const dt = new Date();
  const tdv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();
  if (tdv == dv) GmailApp.sendEmail("your email","Checking if date is today",`The date in row: ${row} and column: ${col} is the same as today`);//edit message if you wish
}


function createTimeBasedTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmail").timeBased().atHour(7).everyDays(1).create();//edit time if needed it will occur somewhere between 7 and 8 am
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)